# Sitemap.xml has the same product in multiple URLS

Tags: sitemap

I am sorry if this question was asked before. But I really dont know what terms to use to look it up.

my sitemap: https://www.zeroohm.com/sitemap.xml

has the same product (resistor 470) repeated 5 times. Is this bad? should I clean my sitemap to show the same product only once?

I am concerned because the sitemap submits about 4000 URLs but my google indexes only about 1130 links.

Here is a sample:

```js
https://www.zeroohm.com/stackpole-electronics-inc.-sei/resistor-470
https://www.zeroohm.com/components/discrete/resistors/resistor-470
https://www.zeroohm.com/components/discrete/resistor-470
https://www.zeroohm.com/components/resistor-470
https://www.zeroohm.com/resistor-470/
```

thanks folks!

Comment: Seems you are using Stackoverflow to point links to your site and get some type of rank. Regardless, shouldn't point links to your site, but make the question more clear/objective.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should. You must avoid having duplicating content on different pages, and if you do, use the canonical url tag. Also the sitemap doesn't make much sense, it should follow a certain logic. You can have links to the resistor-470 page spread through out your site, but they all should point to the same page/url.